# Istio & Celery workers with a Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, service, celery, istio, kiali

Is Istio able to instrument Celery workers with Envoy in a Kubernetes cluster?

Is Kiali able to display Celery workers?

Regards

Comment: Hello @RemiColinet. Could you share some more details regarding your use case scenario? What do you want to achieve and why?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add Istio proxies to your celery workers and enable mTLS.
My setup has istio encrypt the traffic between Redis and the celery worker(s) and they are visible in Kiali.

Comment: Thx for the response. Looks great.